# How to install ROCR package in R?

Tags: r, roc

I want to plot a **ROC curve** using the **ROCR** package in R. I am trying to install the required package but unable to install it. Is there any alternate way of plotting the ROC curve?

Comment: What version of R/RStudio are you using? What have you tried? Do you want to know how to install the package, or plot a ROC curve? Can you show your data/what you want to achieve? Can you give a link to the package you want to install? have you read the install notes to see if your version of R is compatible?

Answer (score 3):

There are some awesome packages for creating ROC Plots and Curves. The three most popular packages are `pROC`, `ROCR` and `PPROC`.

Each package has a different method for generating the plot. Here is a good website to see how to do it for each of these six packages: [Some R Packages for ROC Curves](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2019/03/01/some-r-packages-for-roc-curves/).

Here is a good way to see which packages are the most popular:

```
library(dlstats)
library(dplyr)
shortList <- c("pROC","precrec","ROCit","PRROC","ROCR","plotROC")
downloads <- cran_stats(shortList)
ggplot(downloads, aes(end, downloads, group=package, color=package)) +
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point(aes(shape=package)) +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log2') +
    scale_x_date(date_labels="%Y", breaks="years") +
    labs(title="Downloads Per Package Over Time"
        ,y="Downloads Per Month (log2)"
        ,x="Time"
        ,caption="Souce: \'https://cranlogs.r-pkg.org/downloads/total\'.\nAccessed via package: \'dlsatats\'."
        )
```

This plot looks like this:
[image: Downloads Per Package Over Time]

I trust that helps?

Answer (score 0):

In RStudio in the bottom right window (window that shows: Files | Plots | Packages etc)

1. Click on "Packages"
2. Then Install
3. In the pop-up window :
   Install from: "Repository (CRAN)" then Packages: "ROCR" then tick INSTALL DEPE.. then click INSTALL